# Input a .txt file and lookup Active Directory and output to .CSV

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a list of names that I need to work out the AD usernames for, the list is in the same format as the display name in AD.

I ran the following code

```
Get-Content c:\test\users.txt | 
    Foreach-Object {Get-ADUser -filter "displayName -like '$($_)'" |
    Select-Object SamAccountName,name} |
    Export-Csv c:\test\output1.csv
```

This outputted a list of Usernames and names, however it only outputted successful name resolutions.

What I would like to do is be able to have a list of names to verify against. This could return an error for two reasons:

1. The name was incorrect
2. The user has left the organisation.

For example 
`input.txt` would be a list of names in the format of display name.

Output I would like:

```
Original Input        Exists in AD        Username
Name 1                True                Username1
Name 2                True                Username2 
etc.                  False               Check
```

Many Thanks in Advance

Comment: What if you have two users named "John Smith"? How will you resolve the username from the display name?

Comment: Its against the displayname format, so i input "LastName, FirstName - Business Unit"

Comment: I work at a small college; our typical incoming freshman class size is only about 150. One year we had two incoming freshmen (same "business unit") both with the same first and last names, _and birth date_. Caused no end of issues. Fortunately at least the middle initial was different, but it's never a good idea to count on names as unique.

Comment: This is to run against about 2000 users, we are expecting a 10-15% mismatch between Names in HR and AD as users change names without telling us. We are running this to audit account management. In an ideal world HR would have extracted the email address for us, but trying to make the best of a bad situation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to test if something was returned from `Get-ADUser` and do something else if you got nothing.

I think this should do what you're looking for, but you might want to tweak it:

```
Get-Content c:\test\users.txt | Foreach-Object {
    $user = Get-ADUser -filter "displayName -like '$($_)'" -Properties DisplayName,SamAccountName,Name
    if ($user) {
        $user | Select-Object DisplayName,SamAccountName,Name
    } else {
        $_ | Select-Object @{Label="DisplayName";Expression={"$_"}},@{Label="SamAccountName";Expression={""}},@{Label="Name";Expression={""}}
    }
} |export-csv c:\test\output1.csv
```

If nothing is found, this will output just the display name from the file. All that `Label=` and `Expression=` notation is to make sure it outputs the same properties that are output when something *is* found, so the list can be all put together.

Comment: `Get-ADUser` will trigger a terminating error. You should wrap that in a `try`

Comment: If the user is not found you mean? It didn't for me when I tested this. Errors in PowerShell are not terminating by default unless you expressly tell them to be.

Comment: Ah. It only does that when using `-Identity`

Comment: Thank you Very Much, this does exactly what i was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

You could create a custom object in the pipeline. Also using LDAP filter `anr` (Ambiguous Name Resolution) might work better with the list of names, because it looks up multiple properties of users to find matches.

The solution could be something like this:

```
Get-Content "C:\test\users.txt" |
Foreach-Object {$user=get-aduser -ldapfilter "(anr=$_)"; `
[PSCustomObject]@{Name=$_; Username=$user.samaccountname; Exists=&{$user -ne $null}}} |
Export-Csv "c:\test\output1.csv"
```

Comment: Might be a good to explain `anr` as OP hasn't used this in their code and it's a very useful feature.

Comment: Thank you. Added small explanation. Didn't even notice I had used  `anr` out of habit.

Answer (score 0):

Using this [`Join-Object` cmdlet](https://github.com/iRon7/Join-Object) from the [PowerShell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Join):

```
Get-Content .\Users.txt | ForEach {[PSCustomObject]@{Name=$_; InList=$True}} |
FullJoin (Import-Csv .\output1.csv) Name
```

Will output something like:

```
Name  InList SamAccountName
----  ------ --------------
name1   True Sam1
name2   True
name5   True Sam5
Name3        Sam3
```